# Printing out multiple search results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, append

So, I'm working on a webpage with a search function, where the user can type in an event name and a friend's name, and the page would display search results based on these inputs.

Apologies in advance, my code is an absolute mess (but it works, that's all I care about right now) BUT, my problem is, I don't know a good way to print out all the search results. I looked on the internet and what I have in there right now is the following:

```
$('#searchFeedback').empty();
$.each(data.events[i], function (index, value) {
    $('#searchFeedback').append(output);
})
```

This is the best option I found (and the only one that worked in any way, even if I had to mix in JQuery), but the problem is it prints out the last search result repeatedly and not even the right amount, instead of printing out each of the search results. I'm completely clueless with JQuery.

Here is my entire JS code:

```
<script>

                    function eventSearch() {
                        var eName = document.getElementById("ename").value;
                        var fName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
                        var searchResults = "";
                        var friendResults = "";
                        var attendeeText = "";

                        if (eName === "" && fName === "") {

document.getElementById("searchFeedback").innerHTML = "<h4 class='eName'>Fields cannot be empty!</h4>";

                        } else {

                            for (var i = 0; i < data.events.length; i++) {

                                searchResults = data.events[i].eName.toUpperCase();

                                var output = "<h4 class='eName'>" + data.events[i].eName + " &bull; " + data.events[i].date + "</h4> <p class='eDesc'>" + data.events[i].description + "<br><sub>" + attendeeText + "<a class='event' onclick='openEventLink(" + i + ");' href=''><b> Check it out here.</b> </a></sub></p><br>";

                                if (eName != "" && searchResults.includes(eName.toUpperCase())) {

                                    if (data.events[i].attendees.length != 1) {
                                        for (var a = 0; a < data.events[i].attendees.length; a++) {
                                            attendeeText = data.events[i].attendees.join(", ");
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        attendeeText = data.events[i].attendees;
                                    }


                                    if (data.events[i].attendees.length > 1) {
                                        attendeeText = attendeeText + " are going.";
                                    } else if (data.events[i].attendees.length == 1) {
                                        attendeeText = attendeeText + " is going.";
                                    } else {
                                        attendeeText = "";
                                    }

                                    if (fName != "") {
                                        for (var a = 0; a < data.events[i].attendees.length; a++) {
                                            friendResults = data.events[i].attendees[a].toUpperCase();
                                            if (friendResults.includes(fName.toUpperCase())) {

                                                console.log(searchResults);
                                                console.log(friendResults);

                                                $('#searchFeedback').empty();
                                                $.each(data.events[i], function (index, value) {
                                                    $('#searchFeedback').append(output);
                                                })

                                            }
                                        }


                                    } else {
                                        // Print results
                                    }



                                } else if (eName == "" && fName != "") {
                                    for (var a = 0; a < data.events[i].attendees.length; a++) {

                                        if (friendResults.includes(fName.toUpperCase())) {
                                            console.log(friendResults);
                                            console.log(data.events[i].eName);

                                            if (data.events[i].attendees.length != 1) {
                                                for (var a = 0; a < data.events[i].attendees.length; a++) {
                                                    attendeeText = data.events[i].attendees.join(", ");
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                attendeeText = data.events[i].attendees;
                                            }


                                            if (data.events[i].attendees.length > 1) {
                                                attendeeText = attendeeText + " are going.";
                                            } else if (data.events[i].attendees.length == 1) {
                                                attendeeText = attendeeText + " is going.";
                                            } else {
                                                attendeeText = "";
                                            }

                                           // Print results


                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }    
                    }

                    /* document.getElementById("searchFeedback").innerHTML =
                                                "<h4 class='eName'>" + data.events[i].eName + " &bull; " + data.events[i].date + "</h4> <p class='eDesc'>" + data.events[i].description + "<br><sub>" + attendeeText + "<a class='event' onclick='openEventLink(" + i + ");' href=''><b> Check it out here.</b> </a></sub></p><br>"; */

</script>
```

Thank you so very much!

Edit: Here is the structure of my database. There's loads more stuff in there, but here's the relevant bit.

```
var data = {
   "events": [
      {
        "eName": "The Dalek Invasion of Earth",
        "date": "6.5.2017",
        "time": "10-15",
        "description": "People assume that time is a strict progression of cause-and-effect... but actually, from a non-linear, non-subjective viewpoint, it's more like a big ball of wibbly-wobbly... timey-wimey... stuff. It is! It's the city of New New York! Strictly speaking, it's the fifteenth New York since the original, so that makes it New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New New York. Goodbye...my Sarah Jane! Yeah? Well I'm the Lord of Time. Black tie...Whenever I wear this, something bad always happens.",
        "attendees": ["Jack Harkness", "Rose Tyler"],
        "eLink": "http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Dalek_Invasion_of_Earth_(TV_story)"
      },
      {
        "eName": "The Day of the Doctor",
        "date": "7.5.2017",
        "time": "15-18",
        "description": "I'm sorry. I'm so sorry. There's something else I've always wanted to say: Allons-y, Alonso! I don't want to go. Allons-y! What? What?! WHAT?! It is! It's the city of New New York! Strictly speaking, it's the fifteenth New York since the original, so that makes it New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New New York. Oh, yes. Harmless is just the word: that's why I like it! Doesn't kill, doesn't wound, doesn't maim. But I'll tell you what it does do: it is very good at opening doors!",
        "attendees": ["Amelia Pond", "Donna Noble"],
        "eLink": "http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Doctor_(TV_story)"
      }
  ]
};
```

Edit2: I'll add the HTML of my form as well in case it helps.

```
<div class="eventSearch">
                <h2>Search for events</h2>

                <form id="login" onsubmit="return eventSearch()">
                    <b>By event name:</b> <input type="text" name="ename" id="ename" size="56" placeholder="i.e. The Time War"><br>
                    <b>By a friend's name:</b> <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" size="50" placeholder="i.e. Rose Tyler"><br><br>

                    <input type="radio" name="dates" value="allDates" checked> All events<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="dates" value="pastDates"> Past events<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="dates" value="futureDates"> Future events<br><br>

                    <button type="submit" id="confSearch" name="confSearch" onclick="event.preventDefault(); eventSearch();"><b>Search</b></button><br><br>

                </form>

                <div id="searchFeedback"></div>
```

Even another edit: For further clarification, here is a live version of my webpage: http://users.metropolia.fi/~natalisu/Event%20calendar/main.html

Comment: Maybe its print only last because of `$('#searchFeedback').empty();`?

Comment: Deleting that line makes no difference, so can't be that.

Comment: Ok, what is `data.events[i]` then? Can you show it here?

Comment: I'll add it to the post. One second!

Comment: What purpose for `attendeeText`? and `friendResults`?

Comment: My webpage is an event calendar, so in the database I have a list of "friends", and with each event I want to list the friends attending said event. `attendeeText` is just a way to format the list of attendees, and `friendResults` is the results when the user inputs friend names in the search field.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe it will help

```js
$('button').click(eventSearch);

var data = {
   "events": [
      {
        "eName": "The Dalek Invasion of Earth",
        "date": "6.5.2017",
        "time": "10-15",
        "description": "People assume that time is a strict progression of cause-and-effect... but actually, from a non-linear, non-subjective viewpoint, it's more like a big ball of wibbly-wobbly... timey-wimey... stuff. It is! It's the city of New New York! Strictly speaking, it's the fifteenth New York since the original, so that makes it New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New New York. Goodbye...my Sarah Jane! Yeah? Well I'm the Lord of Time. Black tie...Whenever I wear this, something bad always happens.",
        "attendees": ["Jack Harkness", "Rose Tyler"],
        "eLink": "http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Dalek_Invasion_of_Earth_(TV_story)"
      },
      {
        "eName": "The Day of the Doctor",
        "date": "7.5.2017",
        "time": "15-18",
        "description": "I'm sorry. I'm so sorry. There's something else I've always wanted to say: Allons-y, Alonso! I don't want to go. Allons-y! What? What?! WHAT?! It is! It's the city of New New York! Strictly speaking, it's the fifteenth New York since the original, so that makes it New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New-New New York. Oh, yes. Harmless is just the word: that's why I like it! Doesn't kill, doesn't wound, doesn't maim. But I'll tell you what it does do: it is very good at opening doors!",
        "attendees": ["Amelia Pond", "Donna Noble"],
        "eLink": "http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Doctor_(TV_story)"
      }
  ]
};
function eventSearch() {
    var eName = document.getElementById("ename").value || "";
    var fName = document.getElementById("fname").value || "";
    var searchResultsEname = "";

    var friendResults = "";
    var attendeeText = "";


    $('#searchFeedback').empty();

    if (eName === "" && fName === "") {

        document.getElementById("searchFeedback").innerHTML = "<h4 class='eName'>Fields cannot be empty!</h4>";

    } else {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.events.length; i++) {

            searchResultsEname = data.events[i].eName.toUpperCase();
            

            console.log(searchResultsEname);
            
            console.log(friendResults);

            var output = "<h4 class='eName'>" + data.events[i].eName + " &bull; " + data.events[i].date + "</h4> <p class='eDesc'>" + data.events[i].description + "<br><sub>" + attendeeText + "<a class='event' onclick='openEventLink(" + i + ");' href=''><b> Check it out here.</b> </a></sub></p><br>";

            if (eName != "" && searchResultsEname.includes(eName.toUpperCase())) {

                if (data.events[i].attendees.length != 1) {
                    for (var a = 0; a < data.events[i].attendees.length; a++) {
                        attendeeText = data.events[i].attendees.join(", ");
                    }
                } else {
                    attendeeText = data.events[i].attendees;
                }


                if (data.events[i].attendees.length > 1) {
                    attendeeText = attendeeText + " are going.";
                } else if (data.events[i].attendees.length == 1) {
                    attendeeText = attendeeText + " is going.";
                } else {
                    attendeeText = "";
                }


                $('#searchFeedback').append(output);
                

            } 

            if (fName != "") {

                for (var a = 0; a < data.events[i].attendees.length; a++) {
                    friendResults = data.events[i].attendees[a].toUpperCase();

console.log(friendResults);
                    if (friendResults.includes(fName.toUpperCase())) {

                        $('#searchFeedback').append(output);

                    }
                }
             
                    
            } 
        }
    }
}

eventSearch();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label for="ename">eName    <input type="text" id="ename" value="The Dalek Invasion of Earth"></label>
<label for="fname">fName
<input type="text" id="fname" value=""></label>

<button>Search</button>

<div id="searchFeedback">
  
</div>
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work. Search doesn't work properly, and only one result is shown again.

Comment: This sort of works! It displays the search results as expected, but it searches for both inputs separately, meaning the event name search outputs certain events, and friend name search outputs other events instead of it searching for events which match the event name input as well as the friend name input. So now I sometimes get some events twice. Also, friend search doesn't work on its own.

Comment: Ok. Add more data for case when we get duplicates it could be fixed by removing duplicates by `id` I guess.  And what is `Also, friend search doesn't work on its own`?